# Get the_excerpt of a child page from within a parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

Having trouble getting the excerpt of a child page from within a parent page. I have a static parent page, that within, lists excerpts of all child pages that are hierarchal of that parent.

For some reason I can return each title and publish date of each individual child page. But when I try to echo get_the_excerpt or the_excerpt all I get is the excerpt or content of the parent-page for every child page listed. Also I'm converting the standard excerpt into a custom trimmed excerpt. This worked on the "front-page" but not in a standard "parent-page".

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or overlooking.

This is what appears... note: "The parent page content" repetition.

> ## Parent Page Title
>
> The parent page content
>
> > ### Test Child Page Title A
> >
> > The parent page content
> >
> > *Nov 16, 2016*
> >
> > ### Test Child Page Title B
> >
> > The parent page content
> >
> > *Oct 5, 2016*

Using this solution:

```
<?php
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

// Begin listing all child pages
$childpages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) ); 
 foreach( $childpages as $childpage ) { ?>
  <div class="paged-entries">
    <div class="entry">
      <h3 class="page-headline"><?php echo $childpage->post_title; ?></h3>
        <!-- .entry-summary -->
        <div class="post-excerpt">
            <?php
                    $content = get_extended( $childpage->post_content );
                    $page_excerpt = wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($content);
                    //echo wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($content); // echoes the word "Array" only.
                    //echo $page_excerpt = wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($content); // echoes the word "Array" only.
                    //echo $content['main']; // prints the full child post expected.
                    //print_r ($page_excerpt); // prints full post with some php wrapping: Array ( [main] => This is some fresh music. [extended] => [more_text] => )
                    print_r( $childpage->post_content ); // prints the full child post expected.
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- end .entry-summary -->
        <h6>Published: <?php echo date("M Y", strtotime($pfx_date = get_the_date( $format, $childpage->ID ))); // d m y ?></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is what I'm after:

> ## Parent Page Title
>
> The parent page content
>
> > ### Test Child Page Title A
> >
> > The child page excerpt A
> >
> > *Nov 16, 2016*
> >
> > ### Test Child Page Title B
> >
> > The child page excerpt B
> >
> > *Oct 5, 2016*

**Here is my custom Trimmer**

// Custom Excerpts

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags());
function wpse_allowedtags() {
    return '<video>,<audio>,<embed>,<iframe>,<figure>,<figcaption>'; 
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

function wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($wpse0002_excerpt) {
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $wpse0002_excerpt;
    if ( '' == $wpse0002_excerpt ) {

        $wpse0002_excerpt = get_the_content('');
        $wpse0002_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $wpse0002_excerpt );
        $wpse0002_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $wpse0002_excerpt);
        $wpse0002_excerpt = substr( $wpse0002_excerpt, 0, strpos( $wpse0002_excerpt, '</p>' ) + 4 );
        $wpse0002_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $wpse0002_excerpt);
        $wpse0002_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse0002_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); /*IF you need to allow just certain tags. Delete if all tags are allowed */

        return $wpse0002_excerpt;

    }
    return apply_filters('wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $wpse0002_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}

endif;

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid using `$page` as it's a global variable that refers to the current (i.e parent) page: use a different variable name instead. That might fix your problem.

Comment: `@Dre` that was a well noted update. I'll update the code above. However that didn't fix the problem, I still get the entire post content. Check out my additions above using `@Stanimir Stoyanov` suggestion.

Comment: are you sure `echo get_the_excerpt($childpage->ID)` doesn't work? Also, how are you creating your custom trimmed excerpt?

Comment: @Dre yes. That just prints the excerpt of the actual parent page that I'm displaying the child pages on. See above as I added the custom trim to as well and updated my code above.

Comment: @Dre yes. I should also clarify that I am inside the "LOOP". Doing that using `get_template_part( 'content', 'musicpages' );` Inside music pages is where I then start `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>`, I then perform the custom Foreach, and it shows the entire post fine, but does not trim it period. I've even tried all of this outside the "loop while statement" and to no avail.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why you need a custom filter, but perhaps you have a reason I can't see. Regardless, there's a couple of places this could be breaking: 1) Check that `$content = get_extended( $childpage->post_content)` *is* returning the content you'd expect before you start filtering it. 2) `wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt()` uses `get_the_content()` - I'm pretty sure that returns the content for the *current post in the main loop,* i.e. the parent post. 3) `get_extended()` returns an array, but `wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt()` looks like it's expecting a string.

Comment: @Dre you are correct on all and it is returning the full content I'd expect before filtering. So when I simply change `echo $page_excerpt['main'];` to  'print_r' I get,  `Array ( [main] => This is some fresh music. [extended] => [more_text] => )` you can see my added commented out code above.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like you need `echo wpse0002_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($content['main']);` This basically takes the array `$content`, grabs *just* the 'main' string (i.e. the part before the 'more' tag), and passes it to your custom filtering function. This assumes that your filtering function is doing exactly what you'd expect it to do. I'll admit I'm not entirely clear on what your end goal is, so it's hard to debug. You've hooked your function to the `get_the_excerpt` filter as well; is that intentional?

Comment: @Dre on front page I'm doing [custom excerpts] so that based on a tag of "Featured-Design" or "Featured-Music", each formatted different & does some HTML vs 55char. Works as expected. Now on "Parent Page A", I'm listing all it's child pages on "Parent Page A", hence the custom filter. Trying to use the same excerpt I used for "Featured-Music" to trim it the same. When trying this on a parent page, I get full content of child, not an excerpt. I only get the excerpt of their "Parent Page A". Appears that I can't do this IN or OUT of the LOOP for pages, though Front Page is out of loop and works.

Comment: Weird. Can you zip up your theme templates and functions file, remove/redact anything sensitive and put it on something like Dropbox, and send me a link? I'd like to help you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I've had a quick look, and I think I see the problem. I'll be able to take a closer look and test it at lunch time, so if you can wait a couple of hours I'll have it sorted.

Comment: Ah, that visual does clarify things! I understand now what you were trying to do with your filters. This changes my answer below somewhat; I'll update it in a while to reflect this. So, if I understand this: you want your excerpt to grab the first YouTube embed, audio tag and *then* the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding patronising, I'm going to over-explain everything so that other folks might find this useful. Having gone through it all, I've got a pretty good idea of what you're trying to achieve: there's more than one way to go about it, so rather than just giving you a chunk of code, I'm going to walk through the logic behind it all so you can pick the bits that are applicable.

### Debugging

Firstly, you've got a bunch of PHP errors all over the place, which is leading to some unpredictable behaviour, which suggests you don't have debugging turned on. Add the following to `wp-config.php`:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

This will display warnings and help you track down where the errors are coming form. One notable error is that you're calling `wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt()` without passing an argument.

### Excerpts

By default, pages -- unlike posts -- don't have a separate excerpt field, which is why you've been using `get_extended()` to extract the content before the `more` tag. However, you *can* add the excerpt field to pages by adding the following to `functions.php`. I'd recommend doing this, as it makes all the subsequent excerpt-related behaviour easier. It also means WP should automatically handle the fallbacks for pages that don't have excerpts; no sense re-inventing the wheel.

```
/**
 * Adds excerpt field to pages
 * @args void
 * @returns void
 */
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
```

In the admin area, you might need to check the *Excerpt* option under *Screen Options* to display the field. This lets you use WP's default functions and filters for displaying and manipulating excerpts. It also populates the `$post->post_excerpt` key, so you can use: `echo $post->post_excerpt` if you ever need to output it without filtering.

The other 'gotcha' with excerpts is that `get_the_excerpt()` *has* to be used in the loop; you can't pass it an ID of a post. I'm pretty sure you *used to* be able to do that and it's since been deprecated: methinks the online documentation needs updating, so I'll try and log a change there to spare others confusion in the future. C'est la vie. That brings us on to our next topic...

### Secondary Loops

You're using `get_pages()` to fetch the child pages, which is fine, but because of the way excerpts work you're stuck having to use your own functions for fetching and filtering them. Another approach would be to use `WP_Query` rather than `get_pages()`. As it is the class that powers `get_pages()`, it provides you with some additional control. In this instance, we're interested in the fact that it overwrites the global `$post` variable, which allows `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()` to work correctly. Here's how you can create a secondary loop to fetch the correct child pages:

```
$child_args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,     // This assumes you're calling this on the parent music page
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'sort_order' => 'desc',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,  // Don't display any sticky posts
    'post_type' => 'page'           // Only fetch pages, not posts
); 
$child_query = new WP_Query( $child_args );

// Usual Loop logic
if ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post();

    // You can pretty much do whatever you want in here...
    the_title();    // Should output the child page title
    the_excerpt();  // Should output the child page excerpt
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); // Assigns the excerpt to a variable in case you want to do other things to it.


    endwhile; else: 

    // 'No posts' content would go here

endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); // This is important; it sets $post back to the parent page. Always reset it after a loop.
```

You'd probably want to put this in `page-music.php`, but my personal preference would be to put that in a template part and then call it using `get_template_part()`, which would allow you to easily re-use it on other pages. For example, you should be able to use it the featured design page without having to change a thing.

Also, note the use of `wp_reset_postdata()`: you need to do this at the end of the loop, as it reset the `$post` back to the original page. You want to also do this on `front-page.php`, just after your loop for music pages (round line 81).

For more info on `WP_Query` you can check out [this SO answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts#answer-1755)

### Filtering

Now, if you use secondary loops as described above, you can rely on `$post` being present. This lets you apply conditional filtering on the excerpt, based on the tags, parent page etc. To save having to create different output functions based on the page parent -- as you're currently doing -- you can instead apply a filter function, by adding this to `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Custom function for when we need to filter the excerpt differently for particular pages
 * Needs to be used within the loop
 * @args $excerpt(string)       - The incoming excerpt to filter
 * @args $post(obj)             - The post that the excerpt comes from (WP 4.5+)
 * @returns $excerpt(string)    - The filtered excerpt
 */
if ( !function_exists('custom_excerpt_filter')) {
    function custom_excerpt_filter($excerpt='', $post=null) {

        // Fallback for WP 4.4 and below, which don't pass $post
        if (!$post) {
            global $post;
        }

        // Get the unfiltered excerpt if you really want it:
        // if ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ) {
        //  $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt; // Use an excerpt if there is one.
        // } else {
        //  $excerpt = get_extended($post->post_content)['main']; // Use the content before
        //}


        // Now you can do whatever string manipulations you want with $excerpt here

        // Filtering based on tags...
        if ( has_tag('featured-music',$post) ) {
            // Could apply additional filtering for music page excerpts here
        }

        // Or filtering based on the parent page...
        $parent = get_page_by_path('featured-music'); // Get parent post via the slug
        if ( $post->post_parent == $parent->ID ) {
            // Additional filtering for music child pages here...
        }

        return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt, $post); // Apply other filters so they can be chained
    }
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt','custom_excerpt_filter', 10, 2);
```

I've left out the actual string manipulations on `$excerpt` as you can do pretty much what you like with it.

Now when you use `the_excerpt()` within the loop, your filter can take into account the page tag/parent of the excerpt in question and modify it how ever you want. This way your logic is kept all in one place, and is applied consistently across all templates.

### Inserting media into the excerpt

Since you want to insert video and audio into your excerpt, you'll hit a snag when using the excerpt field in the admin: it won't let you insert any HTML tags. Not to worry, you can still insert it in the content, and extract via our filter. We'll can use [`get_media_embedded_in_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) to extract it from the page content, and then insert it into the excerpt:

```
/**
 * Custom function for when we need to filter the excerpt differently for particular pages
 * Needs to be used within the loop
 * @args $excerpt(string)       - The incoming excerpt to filter
 * @args $post(obj)             - The post that the excerpt comes from.
 * @returns $excerpt(string)    - The filtered excerpt
 */
if ( !function_exists('custom_excerpt_filter')) {
    function custom_excerpt_filter($excerpt='', $post=null) {


        // Fallback for WP 4.4 and below, which didn't pass $post
        // Assumes you're calling this in the loop
        if (!$post) {
            global $post;
        }

        // Get the unfiltered excerpt if you really want it:
        // if ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ) {
        //  $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt; // Use an excerpt if there is one.
        // } else {
        //  $excerpt = get_extended($post->post_content)['main']; // Use the content before
        //}


        // Now you can do whatever string manipulations you want with $excerpt here

        // Filtering based on tags...
        if ( has_tag('featured-music',$post) ) {
            // Could apply additional filtering for music page excerpts here
            $excerpt .= ' has featured music tag';
        }

        // Filtering based on parent...
        $parent = get_page_by_path('featured-music'); // Get parent post via the slug

        if ( $post->post_parent == $parent->ID ) {

            $excerpt = ''; // We ignore the current excerpt as we're making our own

            // First we grab all the content
            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content',  $post->post_content); // Apply content filters so shortcodes get applied

            // Get the audio
            $audio = get_media_embedded_in_content($content, array('audio')); // Returns an array
            if (!empty($audio)) { 
                $audio = $audio[0]; // Since we want the first audio embed, grab the first element in the array
                $excerpt .= $audio; // Add the audio to the excerpt
            } 

            // Get the video
            $video = get_media_embedded_in_content($content, array('video', 'iframe'));
            if (!empty($video)) {
                $video = $video[0];
                $excerpt .= $video; // Add the video to the excerpt
            }

            // Now to get the first paragraph
            // There's a bunch of ways you can do this; you just need to bear in mind that there's media in the content that you'll need to work around
            // Here's one possible way:

            // First, strip out all media...
            $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
            $content = preg_replace("/<iframe[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
            $content = preg_replace("/<audio[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);

            // ...here we're relying on the fact that Wp doggedly wraps everything in <p> tags 
            // Explode the content into an array
            $content = explode('</p>', $content);

            $excerpt .= $content[0];
        }

        return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt, $post); // Apply other filters so they can be chained
    }
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt','custom_excerpt_filter', 10, 2);
```

### Getting the first paragraph

The last thing you want to wrap it all up is to grab the first paragraph. There's a bunch of different ways you could do this; the above function includes one method. You could also:

1. Grabbing the content before the `more` tag using `get_extended()` and then strip out any media using `wp_strip_all_tags()`.
2. Use the separate excerpt field.

### Conclusion

By using `WP_query` and a bit of logic inside your filtering function, you can simplify a lot of your templates, which in turn should in turn help you get everything working correctly. Hopefully it all helps!

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I'll take some time and go through this. It's very kind of you to take time out of your day to enlighten. FYI... the files I sent keep in mind are only partial as I kept it to just the relevant pieces in question sparing the sifting. I have debugging turned on ;)... but, the rest of this is extremely helpful. I'll be sure to let you know what happens.

Comment: Now that I understand what you were attempting to do with the excerpts, I'll update this to add the part about include the video and audio embeds. The above still works: you'll just need to adapt the filter bit at the end. While you're waiting, you might want to look at [`get_media_embedded_in_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) - it takes a string (i.e. your post content) and returns just the embed. It's generally much easier to use an existing function than trying to come up with your own regex.

Comment: @JonnyBorg Updated the above answer to give you a method of pulling in video and audio into the excerpt.

Comment: Incredibly helpful. This is finally working. Very insightful and helpful information. I hope this helps others. I'll share my updates when finished. Thanks again! Also you're comment about Wordpress Documentation needing updated about excerpts is very true. This has been rather confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [get_extended](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended) to get the text before more tag, insead `get_excerpt`. If I am not wrong `get_the_excerpt` returns the content from excerpt field, while `get_extended()` return the content before more tag. So your code will become:

```
$content = get_extended( $page->post_content );
echo $content['main'];
```

Comment: That just returned the word "Array".

Also if I do `$page->ID` that literally shows each unique child pages numerical digit like 111 or 219 etc...

So if I say this:

`echo the_excerpt( $page->ID);`

Comment: My mistake. This function returns an array of content elements. I have updated my answer, so please use the new code.

Comment: Ok yes that works. Thumbs up, but... that is the entire post and not the excerpt. I have a custom trimmed excerpt, so now I need to convert this to just be an excerpt and not the full content. Then I think my custom one should work fine. `echo wpse0001_custom_wp_trim_excerpt();`

Comment: In this case the `$page->post_content` works but `post_excerpt` does not. I would have thought that would pull it's excerpt as it does it's content. `$content = get_extended( $page->post_excerpt ); echo $content['main'];`